# Does anyone know connection points for Speakercraft DB9 to 3.5mm adapter cable?

Tags: serial

I am looking for Speaker craft 3.5mm (4conductor) to DB9 serial cable to program MZC 64 through EZ tools. I am unable to find it online. Does anyone have the cable or know the contact points from 3.5mm to DB9 serial cable for making the cable?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The common layout for the TRS serial cables that I've seen are:

- Tip - Receive
- Ring - Transmit
- Sleeve - Ground

```
 _
\_/  <- Rx
| |  <- Tx
|_|
| |  <- Ground
|_|
```

If you have a TRRS connection, typically the sleve and the lower ring are both ground.

However there's no guarantee this is going to be correct for your specific device (I've no idea what a MZC 64 is). Good news is that you're *unlikely* to mess anything up seriously, so some trial and error might be the way to go.

I would also suggest asking over on our [electrical engineering site](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/). It may not be as simple as just wiring it straight up, there might be TTL logic or level shifting or something else required that's baked into the OEM cable.

Comment: MZC 64 is a Speakercraft made multizone Audio/video amplifier controller. And the cable I am looking for is used for firmware upgrade in MZC 64 and also for programming the MZC 64 for different zones. From the information I have gathered, it is 3.5mm quad plug to DB9 serial adapter.

Comment: As an owner of an MZC-66, I can confirm that the tip is Rx, Upper ring Tx, Lower ring and sleeve are ground.  There are usb->3.5mm cables on aliexpress that have this config